# Strange white dots in range input on webkit

Tags: css, webkit

I'm trying to style range inputs on webkit. Everything works fine on Firefox but webkit display strange white dots around the track.

I read an article about this and took inspiration from it ([link](http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html)).

Now here is the demo. As you can see there are white dots I can't get rid off.

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}
input[type=range] {
  /*removes default webkit styles*/
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
  width: 300px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: goldenrod;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

It must be very simple but I'm still struggling with this.

Thank you

Comment: I guess you pretty much added the border by your self...border: 1px solid white; for the input[type= range]..element....isn't it??

Comment: when I remove it I still have 4 white dots. (updating the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you have four dots is input tag has default background color. i.e. **background-color: white;** from user agent stylesheet.

Try following CSS

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: @DARK_DUCK if the answer solves your issue than don't forget to mark answers as correct

Comment: I know but I had to wait for 1 minute before I can mark it. (Does not make sense to me btw...)